# Browser doesn't interpret smarty

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I downloaded the package Smarty + codeigniter from https://github.com/iarfhlaith/Code-Igniter-and-Smarty, but browset doesen't interpret variable asociate from php.I load library smarty in config/autoload, , but I can not figure out where is the problem.Any suggestion?

In php I have:

```
public function index()
{ 
        $this->smarty->assign('test','This is a test');
        $this->smarty->display('example.tpl');
}
```

and in exemple.tpl:

```
{$test}
```

and browser return {$test} instead of This is a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you even read the **README** on the github project? It says to use the following *code delimiters*:

```
[~$FirstName~]
```

and not:

```
{$FirstName}
```

**Direct copy of quote:**

> the default template code delimiters in Smarty can cause a few issues.
>
> So **{smarty_variable}** becomes **[~smarty_variable~]**.
>
> It's a little more verbose, but gets around having to use {literal}
>   tags everytime you need to add Javascript in your .tpl files.